# Missing References on C# Program System.XML.Contracts

Tags: c#

I am developing a C# program and I found one assemblies not found which is System.XML.Contracts. I tried to find its DLL, but I haven't found any.
Is anyone would give any direction or information about DLL of System.XML.Contracts?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no such assembly or namespace in the .NET System library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is part of [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/).